# Limite puntos highstock 1001 registros

Tags: highcharts

Estaba probando leer muchas medidas y me he dado cuenta que cuando sobrepasa 1000 medidas no me pinta el gráfico.

Si abrís el enlace: http://jsfiddle.net/s6kb5Lpd/

No se ve el gráfico, pero si quitais un solo elemento `["14/03/2018 P16",12.62]` se ve el gráfico.

Los he contado y casualmente falla cuando hay 1001 registros. ¿eso por qué ocurre?

Comment: Si se ve el grafico y no tiene 1000 puntos, esta correcto tu enlace?

Comment: @alanfcm ya lo he cambiado, gracias por avisarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viene predefinido a 1000 puntos, para cambiar el alcance he visto la [propiedad](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold):

```
plotOptions:{
    series:{
        turboThreshold:5000//set it to a larger threshold, it is by default to 1000
    }
}
```